# How to edit NSOutlineView item

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I have a Outlineview using a NSTreeController, for the most part everything is functioning as I would like except when a new item is added, I would like the item automatically selected for editing.  In the past when using a NSTableview I would determine the row the item is located and used the function

```
- (void)editColumn:(NSInteger)columnIndex row:(NSInteger)rowIndex withEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent select:(BOOL)flag
```

However, since NSOutlineView uses NSindexPath, I’m struggling with how to accomplish
this, so is there a function available to pass a NSIndexpath as opposed to a row to achieve the same result.  Or should I have a different approach for NSOutlineView.

Comment: Did you set column as editable in Interface builder??

Comment: Yes, I can double click and edit any item, that's not the problem.  What I need is a way to initiate this programatically.

Comment: Have you tried that method (`editColumn:row:withEvent:select:` that is) as from past experience that seems to have worked for me.

Comment: NSOutlineView doesn't use NSIndexPaths. It uses items, which should be model objects. The items should be the content objects that NSTreeController is directly and indirectly managing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem was related to the addChild method, the documentation for addChild indicates the following;

> **Special Considerations**
>
> Beginning with OS X v10.4 the result of this  method is deferred
>   until the next iteration of the runloop so that the  error
>   presentation mechanism can provide feedback as a sheet.

So, I added the following, with the corresponding selector

```
[self performSelector:@selector(editNewSector:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Everything seems to be working now,my code is below

```
- (IBAction)addChildSector:(id)sender
{
    [[self myTreeController] addChild:sender];
    [self performSelector:@selector(editNewSector:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

- (IBAction)editNewSector:(id)sender
{
    NSTreeNode *nodeSector = [[self myOutlineView]
                                   itemAtRow:[[self myOutlineView] selectedRow]];

    NSInteger row = [[self myOutlineView] rowForItem:nodeSector];
    [[self myOutlineView] editColumn:0 row:row withEvent:nil select:YES];
}
```

Comment: This may fail if the tree controller's `selectsInsertedObjects` is `NO`. I don't know of a better way to get the newly-added item, though.

Comment: i did this. its working fine, But i need How to set default name, Like "untitle folder". could u help me

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just call `editColumn:row:withEvent:select:` on the NSOutlineView:

```
[outlineView editColumn:0 row:editRowIndex withEvent:nil select:YES];
```

Whilst this a method from `NSTableView`, `NSOutlineView` is a subclass of `NSTableView` and thus you can call it on the outline view too.

Comment: And you can get the row index using `rowForItem:`.

Comment: @PeterHosey I added an answer which does give the intended results. But still wondering if this is the best way.